# PromQL get both delta result and current value?

Tags: prometheus, promql, victoriametrics, metricsql

I have the following query:

```
delta(elasticsearch_cluster_health_number_of_nodes[1m]) < 0
```

which will return:

```
{cluster="elasticsearch", container="exporter", endpoint="http", environment="production", instance="x.x.x.x", job="elasticsearch-exporter", namespace="elasticsearch", pod="elasticsearch-exporter-76b7b4b85c-ggds4", prometheus="monitoring/victoria-metrics-vm", service="elasticsearch-exporter"} -1
```

Now, I want to have access to the current number of pods as well. So I tried this:

```
union(
    delta(elasticsearch_cluster_health_number_of_nodes[1m]) < 0, 
    alias(sum(elasticsearch_cluster_health_number_of_nodes[1m]) by(cluster), "current_state"),
)
```

It will return two results (delta and sum) as expected.

The question is - is there a better way of doing this? Also, how can I access the value of aliased query in my alert template?

Comment: There are no `union` nor `alias` operators/functions in PromQL, does it work?

Comment: I've meant MetricsQL, wrote PromQL mistakenly. I have a different query that works with PromQL and provides the same kind of result: ```delta(elasticsearch_cluster_health_number_of_nodes[1m]) < 0 or
label_replace(
    elasticsearch_cluster_health_number_of_nodes[1m],
    "current",
    "true",
    "instance",
    ".*"
)```

Answer (score 1):

> The question is - is there a better way of doing this? Also, how can I access the value of aliased query in my alert template?

In alerts you can do extra [queries right in annotations](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/blob/95ee86b6004b49cc15dcf990232419805677558a/app/vmalert/config/testdata/rules/rules2-good.rules#L11-L22):

```
  - alert: Conns
    expr: vm_tcplistener_conns > 0
    for: 3m
    annotations:
      labels: "Available labels: {{ $labels }}"
      summary: Too high connection number for {{ $labels.instance }}
        {{ with printf "sum(vm_tcplistener_conns{instance=%q})" .Labels.instance | query }}
          {{ . | first | value }}
        {{ end }}
      description: "It is {{ $value }} connections for {{$labels.instance}}"
```

See https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmalert.html#template-functions