# How can i use arithmetic operations in the description of a Prometheus Alert?

Tags: prometheus, alert, go-templates, prometheus-alertmanager

I have an alert in Prometheus that fires if a SSL Certificate expires 29 days from now.

The Alert works perfectly fine. The problem is the Value it returns is not in days.
The query i use is as follow: `probe_ssl_last_chain_expiry_timestamp_seconds - time() < 86400 * 29`

Now i would like to have the number of days in my description as following:

`description: "SSL certificate expires in {{ $value }} days"`

But for it to be the real number of days i have to divide the value by 86400.

Here is what i already tried:

`description: "SSL certificate expires in {{ $value/86400 }} days"`
`description: "SSL certificate expires in {{ printf \"%0.2f\" (div $value 86400) }} days"`
`description: "SSL certificate expires in {{ (div $value 86400) }} days"`
`description: "Expires in {{ $value | printf \"%.2f\" | div 86400 }}"`
`description: "Expires in {{ (div $value 86400) | printf \"%.2f\" }}"`

I expected to value to be returned in actual days. Instead i get a error message from prometheus.

How can i achive that?

Is there a way to achieve this? Maybe i can record the value and insert it like this?

Any solution seems welcome.

Thank you

Comment: I found a solution to my problem. I changed the query so the values returned are in days:

(probe_ssl_last_chain_expiry_timestamp_seconds - time())/86400 < 29

But it still does not answer my question if i can use arithmetic operations directly in the description. And how if it even is possible

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus' Alertmanager uses [go templates](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template), and I don't think they support arithmetic out of the box.

Your idea of using `(probe_ssl_last_chain_expiry_timestamp_seconds - time())/86400 < 29` is usually correct for this kind of issue.

If you need both divided and not values, or if you need to include result of another metric, [you can include it through `query` instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75248345/21363224).